# How to mask an email address using a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

Original email :

```
aaron.gjesddf@example.com
```

Masked email:

```
aar****@example.com
```

I need help in writing one expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/Kx0V3B/1)

Email (only the first 3 letters should be displayed )

Comment: I think it's simpler to split by `'@'`, replace the first element and join the array elements.

Comment: once you split by @ you can trim the left string leaving only 3 chars and append as many other * as you wish without regexp to be involved

Comment: Anyone with 3 or less letters in the prefix of their email address is out of luck I guess... haha.

Comment: Are you sending the mail address over the network? If so, it's pretty useless to mask it on frontend side.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

`(?<=.{3}).(?=[^@]*?@)`

Demo link is [here](https://regex101.com/r/skbTKS/1)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any regex, you can simply do.

```js
let email = "aaron.gjesddf@example.com"

console.log(email.split("@")[0].slice(0,3)); 
// output: aar
```

Now, you can append as many `*` you want.

> Regex is a heavy context in any programming language and not everyone understand, so do not let other developer confuse while reading your code.

You can use below code for complete understanding.

```js
let email = "aaron.gjesddf@example.com"
let chunks = email.split("@");
console.log(`${chunks[0].slice(0,3)}***@${chunks[1]}`)
// output: aar***@example.com
```

Comment: If it works bro, then consider upvoting and accepting my answer.